# Javascript enabling buttons works in JSFiddle but not in browser - Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am using Python/Flask to develop a web app.

In a page I want to have some buttons disabled initially, and then enabled if a function is called.

In JSFiddle for example something like this works:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xuyy3han/3/)

However, if in my `index.html` file I have something like this:

```
{%- extends "base.html" %}

{% import "bootstrap/utils.html" as utils %}

{% block content %}

  <h1>Three buttons!</h1>
  <div id="audio">
    <p>
      <button id=startRecord onclick="startRecording()">Start</button>
      <button id=stopRecord onclick="stopRecording()">Stop</button>
      <button id=submitRecord onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
    </p>
    <p>
      <audio id=recordedAudio></audio>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a id=audioDownload></a>
    </p>
  </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
  <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/recordtest.js')}}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Where `recordtest.js` is:

```
startRecord.disabled = false;
stopRecord.disabled = true;
submitRecord.disabled = true;

function startRecording() {
  stopRecord.disabled = false;
}
```

All buttons start as enabled and are not changed with the function.

I am using Chrome.

Comment: if that is the content of your `index.html` in the browser, then it will not process this `src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/recordtest.js')}}"` but rather take it literally and fail at loading the url. Did you check the network-tab in your dev-tools for the script?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly put an alert in startRecording function to confirm that it is actually getting called, try the code like this

```
document.getElementById("startRecord").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("stopRecord").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("stopRecord").style.backgroundColor = '#aaa'; // or any color you need to make it look like its hidden
document.getElementById("submitRecord").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("submitRecord").style.backgroundColor = '#aaa'; // or any color you need to make it look like its hidden

function startRecording() {
  alert();
  document.getElementById("stopRecord").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("stopRecord").style.backgroundColor = '#FFF'; // or any color you need to make it look like its not hidden
}
```

Also Verify that your java-script files are properly linked, that's probably the cause

Comment: That works, but for some reason the disabled buttons are just not clickable, but not grey (clearly seen as disabled) which is also wanted. How do I do that?

Comment: well you could add additional JavaScript that changes the background color of the buttons to be hidden there's no harm in doing that. Ive edited my code to show how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Put following lines in your js files in a self executing javascript closure, something like written below.

```
$(function(){
    startRecord.disabled = false;
    stopRecord.disabled = true;
    submitRecord.disabled = true;

    function startRecording() {
      stopRecord.disabled = false;
    } 
})();
```

Also, put type="text/javascript" in script tag for neatness.